# how to multiply and group values of NDVI in Erdas

Tags: erdas-imagine, modis, ndvi

I have downloaded the MODIS data for calculating the NDVi but the ranges of values in its attribute table ranges from -32768 to 9830  i want to club the similar values upto 2 decimal places and  also want to multiply these values with scaling factor of 0.0001

Could somebody please help by expalining me how to do this in erdas

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what version of erdas are you using,
but in erdas 2011:

go to raster - > radiometric -> rescale
and choose your min/max values and it will stretch all values. 
i dont know about the 2 decimal format.